# Design of Wheels/Tires for a RC Car

Tags: design, friction, wheels

Background Information:

My design team is trying to create a small RC car that can climb a 30 degrees incline that is 6inches high. We have two motors on a 3 wheels vehicle with the motors powering the 2 back wheels. The wheels are about 20cm length and 18cm width (15cm without) with the tires. The tires we currently have are made of plastic. The track is painted on wood so is pretty slippery. 4 double A batteries for each wheel.

**Our vehicle is unable to make it up the incline.**

What are some ways to make the vehicle go up the incline?

Comment: Welcome to Engineering SE. As it stands the question is too broad and is subject to be close. May I suggest you add more detail and narrow down the scope. I suggest including specification of the two motors, details to drive HW and SW (If any), weight of the RC Car. Does to RC car climb an incline of 15 degrees etc

Comment: Sounds like you just need to increase friction on the tires.  A few rubber bands would probably work.

Comment: I agree with Mahendra that there isn't quite enough information to answer the question currently. I think, at the least, we need the weight of the car in its current state and the specs on the motors powering the wheels. Also, can you clarify if 20cm length for the wheels means 20cm diameter? And are the tires pneumatic (air-inflated) or hard plastic? Lastly, the behavior of the car will help as well. Does it spin its tires or can it not even turn them? Do the tires all spin simultaneously or is it just the front as they approach the ramp?

Comment: I'm placing your question on hold as "unclear" so you have the time to [edit] your question and provide the requested details.  Placing the question on hold prevents other, perhaps speculative answers from coming in that may be invalidated based upon your pending [edit]s

Answer (score 1):

I'm going out on a limb and assuming that the reason the car doesn't make it up the incline is because the wheels are too slippery.  Therefore, you'll want to increase the coefficient of friction between the wheels and the ramp.  You can do this many different ways, but in general you need to add some material to your wheels that's softer/stickier than the current plastic.  The simplest way would be to wrap a few rubber bands around the wheels.  You could also cut some rubber sheeting (available at Home Depot, etc.) to fit around the wheel and glue it on.  The possibilities are endless.